# How to properly store element count in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I'm pretty new to Protractor and I'm not satisfied with the way I wrote the code below (which is actually working).
I would like to simply store the count in a variable (here, "nb_before") and reuse it after, but the promise mechanism won't allow me to do it concisely, so I decided to put everything in the same function. But it's so ugly.
Am I missing something?
Best regards

```
    // We count the lines, we click on a button which adds a new line,
    // then we verify that the new line has a specific text.

    it("Test case", function () {
        browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
        var button = element(by.xpath("//whatever"));
        var rows = element.all(by.xpath("//whatever"));
        rows.count().then(function(count){
            nb_before = count;
            button.click(); // adds a line
            var nb_after = nb_before + 1;
            var new_line = element(by.xpath("//li[" + nb_after + "]"));
            expect(new_line.getText()).toEqual("yay");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where do you want to reuse it? You can get rid of `nb_before` and just use `count`

Comment: In pseudo code, that's what I want to do:
`var nb_before = element.all(by.xpath("//whatever").count(); // something concise like this (I'm from Java world and it's actually more straightforward in this case)` (without all the promise structure) And I don't want to get rid of `nb_before` because I want to know if a line has actually been added.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could've used [`.last()` method](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.last) here to get the last row:

```
it("Test case", function () {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);

    var button = element(by.xpath("//whatever"));
    var rows = element.all(by.xpath("//whatever"));

    button.click(); // adds a line

    expect(rows.last().getText()).toEqual("yay");
});
```

We can, though, get the count before and after the button click and check if it was incremented by one - this will still require us to use `.then()` to resolve the promise returned by `.count()`:

```
var button = element(by.xpath("//whatever"));
var rows = element.all(by.xpath("//whatever"));

rows.count().then(function (countBefore) {
    button.click();
    expect(rows.count()).toEqual(countBefore + 1);
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but it doesn't help me with storing the element count. I won't always have to check the very last item. Sometimes I use the element count to click on a random item. Thank you

Comment: @Y-BCause right, but, the point is, do you really need to know the count? Here, we are just getting to the last row without knowing how many rows are there..

Comment: In this case, I totally agree with you, I could find a workaround. But this is not the point, I want to learn how, in any context, I could store the count in a variable.

Comment: @Y-BCause okay, please see if the second code example in the answer is on the right track. The point is, if you need an actual "count" value, you'll have to resolve the `count()` promise somewhere anyway. Thanks.